# insert carriage return every x characters

Tags: c#

I have a large file that was given to us without any end of record reference. I need to insert a \r\n every X characters. when I attempted this, the length gets screwed up after the first insert.

What is the best way to insert \r\n based on a record length?

Thanks!

Comment: "length gets screwed up after the first insert" what do you mean by that? Do you expect to insert new characters without modifying the string's original length?

Comment: You'll have to work backwards from the end of the string.

Comment: I've not found anything that deals with parsing a string x characters with iterate in reverse... can anyone provide a link?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Regex.Replace` for it:

```
Regex.Replace(
    longText
,   "(.{5})" // Replace 5 with X
,   "$1\r\n"
)
```

The idea is to capture substrings of a fixed length `X` into a capturing group number 1, and then replace them with the content of that group (denoted as `$1`) followed by `\r\n`.

[Demo on ideone.](http://ideone.com/yvRH1M)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do you. It takes a source file consisting of fixed length records with a given encoding and transforms it to "normal" CR+LF delimited records. There is, of course, an implicit assumption that the file contains textual data.

```
public static void ConvertFixedLengthRecordsToDelimitedRecords( FileInfo sourceFile , Encoding sourceEncoding , int recordLength )
{
  if ( sourceFile == null ) throw new ArgumentNullException("sourceFile");
  if ( !sourceFile.Exists ) throw new ArgumentException("sourceFile does not exist" , "sourceFile" ) ;
  if ( sourceEncoding == null ) throw new ArgumentNullException("sourceEncoding");
  if ( recordLength < 1 ) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("recordLength");

  // create a temporary file in the temp directory
  string tempFileName = Path.GetTempFileName() ;

  // copy the source file to the temp file 1 record at a time, writing each record as a line.
  //
  // NOTE: If the source data contains '\r', '\n' or '\r\n', you'll get short records in the output
  // You might consider throwing an exception or figuring out how to deal with that.
  using ( FileStream   inStream  = sourceFile.Open( FileMode.Open , FileAccess.Read , FileShare.Read ) ) 
  using ( StreamReader input     = new StreamReader( inStream , sourceEncoding ) )
  using ( Stream       outStream = File.Open( tempFileName , FileMode.Truncate , FileAccess.Write , FileShare.Read ) )
  using ( StreamWriter output    = new StreamWriter( outStream , Encoding.UTF8 ) )
  {
    char[] buf = new char[recordLength];
    int bufl ;

    while ( 0 != (bufl = input.ReadBlock( buf , 0 , buf.Length )) )
    {
      output.WriteLine(buf,0,bufl) ;
    }
  }

  // at this point, the temporary file contains the fixed-length source records at CR+LF terminated lines.
  // We just need to replace the source file with the temp file.
  FileInfo tempFile = new FileInfo( tempFileName ) ;
  string backupFileName = sourceFile.FullName + ".bak" ;
  File.Delete( backupFileName ) ;
  tempFile.Replace( sourceFile.FullName , backupFileName ) ;

  return ;
}
```